# Is Rascal correctly wearing a real type of backpack?

Tags: rascal-does-not-dream-of-bunny-girl

In the first set of opening credits for *Rascal Does Not Dream of Bunny Girl Senpai* we see a short scene of Rascal wearing an unusual type of backpack in a way I have never seen before.
[image: Rascal from the back, wearing narrow, low backpack.]

I have only watched the first three episodes, and I don't believe there has been context for this picture presented. I've never seen such a narrow backpack before, but I'll assume they exist.  Several characteristics strike me as odd:

1. By as low as it sits, it is as much as a "butt pack" as a backpack, at least as Rascal is wearing it.
2. The upper straps are shown restricting his arms. Is he unnecessarily binding his arms, or is that the proper way to wear it?
3. If the backpack were raised high enough for the upper straps to fit over his shoulders (common for most backpacks I believe), then the lower strap would seem to fit around his upper chest, which also seems unusual.

Is this a real world item being worn the way it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's the same type of bag that the other students have, but he is wearing it on his back, wrapping his hands through the straps instead of holding it over his shoulder.

User Gorzius illustrated this for us below!

[image]

I'll admit it looks slightly disproportionate in the photo from the opening.

[image]

To answer your question then, I would say yes, handbags like this [are real.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G8E2F1O)

[image]

Comment: I used my extraordinary drawing skills to show how the [straps go around](https://i.imgur.com/HZgsdNq.jpg) Rascal's arm, and that they're not top and bottom straps at all, but left and right.

Comment: Nice! Do you mind if I add that to the post? @Gorzius

Comment: Feel free, that's why I made it! - But now I see I forgot to mention that -_-  @Michael McQuade

Comment: Once I got my eyes to envision what @Gorzius drew, I see the left & right looped straps now.  So I accepted this answer, which really belongs to you both.  The backpack still seems to be riding really low; perhaps it slipped down from his shoulders.

Comment: @RichF I don't think it slipped down, he's just wearing it like that for whatever reason or without any reason at all. I remember when I was in school I used to slip down my backpack in a similar fashion. As of why? I don't know. Probably because why not.